# Turn Off Logging in playOrm

Tags: playorm

Is there a way to turn off the INFO logging in playOrm? I have tried setting my log4j.xml config to

```
<!-- Application Loggers -->
<logger name="com.alvazan">
    <level value="off" />
</logger>
```

and

But I still get a tone of INFO logging from com.alvazan.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The log4j lead left and created slf4j and logback logging.  playOrm uses SLF4J which means you need to do some jar swapping so the impl that SLF4j uses is log4j and then that will work jsut fine.  By default we use logback as the implementation since the log4j dude recommends that.(ALL you need to do is change the logback jars and swap them out for slf4j-log4j jars and it will work for you and remove the log4j-over-slf4j.jar as well).

A basic rundown is if you use SLF4J in your library you can work in any platform no matter what logging they use....log4j, jdk, commons, etc. etc.  commons had classloading issues while SLF4j does not.  REad up on SLF4j but here is a quick run down.

SLF4j has 4 adapter jars so that logging to log4j goes to SLF4j and logging to jdk logging goes to SLF4j api and commons, etc. etc. EXCEPT if you use that jars impl.  You include ALL these jars so you can control the logging of all libraries in your platform through one config file.

THEN there is the api jar.

THEN there is 4 implementation jars.  UNlike the adapter jars where you NEED to inclue ALL of them, in this case you PICK ONE SINGLE impl jar or slf4j will log a nice big warning and pick one itself.  In your case, pick the log4j implementation and you can then control all libraries even if they log to the jdk or commons logging frameworks as well.

Dean

Comment: Thanks Dean. Removing the logback dependency and adding the slf4j-api jars did  the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit pom.xml to exclude lobback-classic:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.alvazan</groupId>
      <artifactId>playorm</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```